# What is the difference between hitting the GO button in IE and hitting Enter key directly after pasting a URL?

Tags: internet-explorer, url

What is the difference between

- hitting the GO button and
- hitting the Enter key

directly after pasting a URL in the address bar of Internet Explorer?

In my cases, for the first time in Internet Explorer, it is behaving differently.

Comment: How does it behave "differently"?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, there is no difference.  Clicking the go button and hitting enter immediately after pasting the URL should both launch the page.  If the focus shifts to another place after you past the URL and before you hit enter it could behave differently.

That being said, slhck is right, more information about how it behaves differently is needed before a more definitive answer can be given.